# How to read Toast Notification attributes in Windows Phone 8.1?

Tags: windows, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I have created below toast notification

```
ToastTemplateType toastType = ToastTemplateType.ToastText02;
XmlDocument toastXml = ToastNotificationManager.GetTemplateContent(toastType);
XmlNodeList toastTextElement = toastXml.GetElementsByTagName("text");
toastTextElement[0].AppendChild(toastXml.CreateTextNode("Hello C# Corner"));
toastTextElement[1].AppendChild(toastXml.CreateTextNode("I am poping you from a Winmdows Phone App"));
IXmlNode toastNode = toastXml.SelectSingleNode("/toast");
((XmlElement)toastNode).SetAttribute("duration", "long");
((XmlElement)toastNode).SetAttribute("type", "Employee");
((XmlElement)toastNode).SetAttribute("launch", "<cat state='angry'><facebite state='true' /></cat>");
ToastNotification toast = new ToastNotification(toastXml);
ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier().Show(toast);
```

I want to know how to access the **type** attribute.

When I tried with below code it's returning null

```
var att = toast.Content.Attributes;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debugging shows you the answer.

```
 var att = toast.Content.ChildNodes[0].Attributes[1].NodeValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var att = 
toast.Content
.SelectSingleNode("/toast/visual/binding")
.SelectNodes("text")[0].InnerText
```